# React state nested Object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I have `useEffect()` and it fetch data from API and pass it to React State called `companyData`

The API response looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date1": {
        "BalanceSheet": {
                   ... {JSON DATA}
        },
        "CashFlow": {
                    ... {JSON DATA}
        },
        "IncomeSheet": {
          ... {JSON DATA
      }
    
  ]
}
```

And my useEffect and State looks like ..

```
const [companyData,setCompanyData] = useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`/api/company/view/${id}`).then((res)=>{
    setCompanyData(res.data[0]) 
  })
},[])
```

So when i am try to access `companyData.date1.CashFlow` ( outside useEffect )

Like this  `console.log(companyData.date1.CashFlow)`

it returns `TypeError: companyData.date1 is undefined`

But if i try to console.log the `companyData` or `companyData.date1`
it returns the JSON without any errors

My React Component Code:

```js
export default function YourAnalysis(props){
const [companyData,setCompanyData] = useState({});
const [tableToShow,setTableToShow] = 
useState({incomesheet:false,balancesheet:false,cashflow:true});
const id = props.match.params.id 
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get(`/api/company/view/${id}`).then((res)=>{
    setCompanyData(res.data[0]) 

  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log('an error')
  })

},[])




function renderTable(){
  if(tableToShow.incomesheet){
       return (<div></div>)
  }
  if(tableToShow.balancesheet){
    return (<div></div>)
  }
  if(tableToShow.cashflow){
 console.log(companyData) // works fine
 console.log(companyData.date1.CashFlow) // date1 is undefined 

  }
  
}
```

I thought it's because the API response async and it takes time to assign\set data to `companyData` State,
the weird thing is that i can access and log the `companyData` or `companyData.date1` i'll see the JSON data and everything is good
but when i try to access `companyData.date1.CashFlow` or `companyData.date1.BalanceSheet` or `companyData.date1.IncomeSheet`it returns undefined

maybe it because the name of `date1`?

or react has a method to deal with nested json object?

Any help? i am newbie in react

Comment: show the code where you get the error. where you have the console.log

Comment: Ok, i'll do that, just a minute

Comment: Wouldn't it be `res.data.data[0]` since Axios puts the response body into a `data` property, and your own response is nested in a `data` property as well?

Comment: Here's a really similar question: [Axios gets undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43701038/1218980)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Check again the question i added the whole code, the error isn't from the axios response, it's from The state

Comment: whats the exact output of `console.log(companyData) `

Comment: Fetching through axios is async, setting the state is async, `companyData.date1.CashFlow` will always fail until every async code is completed.

Comment: Also, even if there's no error, `res.data[0]` will return `undefined` since your response isn't an array.

Comment: if your api response is correct you should be doing `console.log(companyData[0].date1.CashFlow)` right?

Comment: @Mint `console.log(companyData)` returns JSON data that inside the api response Array

Comment: @EmileBergeron `res.data[0]` the api response is an array inside it a object
so `res.date[0]` it returns the object that inside the array

Comment: api response returns array with one item,
inside it Object data

Comment: @Mint 
`console.log(companyData[0].date1.CashFlow)` returns companyData[0] is undefined
because i passed on state the object that inside the api response Array
so it's not an array

Comment: That's not what you've shown in the question then!

Comment: @EmileBergeron Sorry i edited the question, check it again please,
just to notice,
`companyData` it works
`companyData.date1` it works
but if i try to access objects inside the `date1`
it doesn't work

Comment: I've seen your edit, which confirms all that I've already said above (and answers you've received as well), or you've provided a different API response than the one you're really receiving on your end.

Comment: `if(companyData) conosle.log(companyData.date1)`

Comment: @Mint won't work since `companyData` is always an object on the first render.

Comment: Then perform the check on the length? `if(Object.keys(companyData).length !== 0)`

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yep, I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850047/react-how-to-wait-data-before-using-this-state-x-into-a-function)  and that what i really want! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mint it works by checking the length for the json, your way is much easier, thanks a lot !

Comment: @EmileBergeron when you said that: Wouldn't it be `res.data.data[0]` 
you're right in this point, but the API response that i show in my question it's the axios response but i removed the objects except the `data` object

Comment: Yeah I figured that it was either this or the missing condition, which is why it's really important to provide a [mcve]! Happy you resolved the issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your component is rendered at first, you will have empty object as your `companyData`, as you provide `{}` in `useState()`. Your object will not be empty only after request completes.

So your `console.log` at first render is actually `{}.date1.CashFlow` - undefined error.
Either use a flag to understand that data arrived, or provide some default non-empty object for your state in `useState`

Comment: Yes Exactly! Thanks, I dealt with this by providing a default object for my state called `isloaded` and if the data is loaded then the value for this state will be true, according to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850047/react-how-to-wait-data-before-using-this-state-x-into-a-function)

Comment: another way i did it, by checking the length for the Object

Comment: but can you explain to me, what do you mean when you said `flag`

Comment: Flag usually is some Boolean variable, isLoaded - is exactly what I meant and what I called flag

Answer (score 2):

It's because the useEffect() mocks Componentdidmount and Componentwillupdate which means that when you try to console log the data outside the useEffect the data is actually is not loaded yet.
use this code to see the data;

```
if(data){
//  your logic
}
```

and use states to store the data as nikita suggested in her answer

Comment: Thanks a lot you and nikita,
I dealt with this by providing a default object for my state called `isloaded` and if the data is loaded then the value for this state will be true, according to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850047/react-how-to-wait-data-before-using-this-state-x-into-a-function)

Comment: another way i did it, by checking the length for the Object